# Extract one specific value from table/csv to draw an horizontal line

Tags: plot, csv

I need to add horizontal lines (asymptotes) to a plot made from a csv file, with the y-axis value taken from this last. I found an example to draw the horizontal lines

```
\addplot [thick,black]
table[x=freq,y=mod2,col sep=space] {file.csv};
\coordinate (A) at (axis cs:0,-74.927351816709300);
\coordinate (O1) at (rel axis cs:0,0);
\coordinate (O2) at (rel axis cs:1,0);              
\draw [red,sharp plot,dashed] (A -| O1) -- (A -| O2);
```

but I have to add the specific value `-74.927351816709300` and `-87.967485127488640` manually. How can I read it automatically form csv file?
The resulting figure should be as follow

[image]

Maybe there is a better solution (tell me!) but anyway the need to extract a value from a csv file remains. Following the compilable code (there are redundant packages)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,useprefix,hyperref,backend=bibtex,indexing]{biblatex}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[english]{varioref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{floatflt}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[small,normal,bf]{caption}
\usepackage[binding=0.5cm]{layaureo}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    grid=both,
    major grid style={dashed, draw=gray!40},
    minor grid style={dashed, draw=gray!15},
    every axis/.append style={
        label style={font=\small},
        tick label style={font=\tiny}},
    compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}


\begin{document}

    \chapter{Test}

    \begin{figure*}[t]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
            xmode=log,
            ymode=normal,
            xlabel=$frequency$,
            x unit=\si{\hertz},
            ylabel=$attenuation$,
            y unit=\si{\decibel},
            width=\linewidth,
            no marks
            ]
            \addplot [thick,black]
            table[x=freq,y=mod1,col sep=space] {file.csv};
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{}
            \label{fig:test1}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hspace{5pt}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
            xmode=log,
            ymode=normal,
            xlabel=$frequency$,
            x unit=\si{\hertz},
            ylabel=$attenuation$,
            y unit=\si{\decibel},
            width=\linewidth,
            no marks
            ]
            \addplot [thick,black]
            table[x=freq,y=mod2,col sep=space] {file.csv};
            \coordinate (A) at (axis cs:0,-74.927351816709300);
            \coordinate (B) at (axis cs:0,-87.967485127488640);
            \coordinate (O1) at (rel axis cs:0,0);
            \coordinate (O2) at (rel axis cs:1,0);              
            \draw [red,sharp plot,dashed] (A -| O1) -- (A -| O2);
            \draw [blue,sharp plot,dashed] (B -| O1) -- (B -| O2);
            \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{}
            \label{fig:test2}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \caption{This is a test.}
        \label{fig:vcm2diff_ele}
    \end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

and a part of my csv file (the original has more than 100k rows)

```
freq mod1 pole1_1 pole1_2 zero1_1 zero1_2 mod2 pole2_1 pole2_2 zero2_1 zero2_2
0.01 -57.0934586472708 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273518167093 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0102329299228075 -57.0934594712561 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273518315012 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.010471285480509 -57.0934603340746 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273518469901 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0107151930523761 -57.0934612375562 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273518632091 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0109647819614319 -57.0934621836174 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273518801924 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0112201845430196 -57.093463174265 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273518979761 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0114815362149688 -57.0934642116001 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.927351916598 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0117489755493953 -57.0934652978231 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273519360974 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0120226443461741 -57.0934664352379 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273519565159 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0123026877081238 -57.0934676262571 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273519778966 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0125892541179417 -57.093468873407 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.927352000285 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0128824955169313 -57.093470179333 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273520237285 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0131825673855641 -57.0934715468049 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273520482769 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0134896288259165 -57.0934729787235 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273520739822 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0138038426460289 -57.0934744781258 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273521008989 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0141253754462275 -57.0934760481922 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273521290842 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0144543977074593 -57.0934776922531 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273521585979 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0147910838816821 -57.0934794137956 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273521895024 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0151356124843621 -57.0934812164712 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273522218635 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0154881661891248 -57.0934831041036 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273522557497 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0158489319246111 -57.0934850806965 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273522912329 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0162181009735893 -57.0934871504426 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273523283883 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0165958690743756 -57.0934893177318 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273523672949 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0169824365246174 -57.0934915871612 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.927352408035 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0173780082874938 -57.0934939635443 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273524506952 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0177827941003892 -57.0934964519217 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273524953659 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0181970085860998 -57.0934990575713 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273525421418 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0186208713666287 -57.0935017860199 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273525911223 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0190546071796325 -57.0935046430547 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273526424111 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0194984459975805 -57.0935076347355 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273526961171 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0199526231496888 -57.093510767408 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273527523541 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0204173794466953 -57.0935140477166 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273528112416 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0208929613085404 -57.093517482619 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273528729043 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0213796208950223 -57.0935210794007 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273529374731 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0218776162394955 -57.0935248456906 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273530050849 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0223872113856834 -57.0935287894772 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273530758832 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0229086765276777 -57.0935329191253 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273531500181 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0234422881531992 -57.0935372433939 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273532276468 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0239883291901949 -57.0935417714549 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273533089341 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0245470891568503 -57.0935465129123 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273533940523 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0251188643150958 -57.0935514778226 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273534831821 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0257039578276886 -57.0935566767166 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273535765123 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0263026799189538 -57.0935621206208 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273536742412 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0269153480392692 -57.0935678210819 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273537765758 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0275422870333817 -57.0935737901901 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273538837333 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0281838293126445 -57.0935800406059 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.927353995941 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0288403150312661 -57.093586585586 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273541134368 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0295120922666639 -57.093593439012 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273542364701 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0301995172040202 -57.0936006154197 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273543653018 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0309029543251359 -57.0936081300296 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273545002051 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0316227766016838 -57.0936159987796 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273546414662 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0323593656929628 -57.0936242383587 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273547893847 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0331131121482591 -57.0936328662421 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273549442744 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0338844156139203 -57.0936419007287 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273551064639 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0346736850452532 -57.0936513609794 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.927355276297 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0354813389233576 -57.0936612670581 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273554541342 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
0.0363078054770101 -57.0936716399742 6.40405640412163 5.34407576904492 131.699566676134 26.458678866504 -74.9273556403526 63.24510750837 52.7116183559185 117.420699760983 117.420699760983
```

Comment: Welcome! Hard to say without seeing `file.csv` and, preferably, compilable code.

Comment: At this time I can't add the file, but it has floating values disposed on some columns separated by space. Every column has a header as first row. That's all. As soon as possible I'll post a compilable code.

Comment: How do you get those values from that file?

Comment: I'm using the pgfplots package to graph plots. The command I use is `table[x=freq,y=mod2,col sep=space] {file.csv};`

Comment: Please make your code into a compilable example. But I meant: how do you get -74.927351816709300 and -87.967485127488640  from the values shown in the `.csv` you've posted?

Comment: Ok, I added the compilable code and a part of the actual csv file

Comment: Thanks, but how do you derive those values from that file? It doesn't contain `-74.927351816709300`, for example, so what's the rule for getting it?

Comment: In the example code I insert it manually with the command `\coordinate (A) at (axis cs:0,-74.927351816709300);`. In the file the value is in the 7th column.

Comment: No it isn't. It is nowhere in that file. I've used the search to search it at least twice and both times the computer says: it ain't there to find. But, in any case, what is it about that value in that column? You've given no idea what the criteria are for extracting one value rather than another.

Comment: The value in the file change in the last digit; the value in the file is `-74.927352408035`. The criteria is simple: I want the value in the 1st row of the 7th column.